# Set all elements left to index to one, right of index to zero for list of indices

Tags: numpy

Say I have a list of Indices:

```
np.array([1, 3, 2, 4])
```

How do I create the following matrix, where all elements left to the index are ones and right to the index zeros?

```
[[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1*(np.arange( 6 ) <= arr[:,None])
# array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

This broadcasts the array of 6 elements across the rows and the array of indices across the columns.  The 1* converts boolean to int.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot